# Laravel 5.3 Mail always set to mailtrap.io even though changed

Tags: email, laravel-5

In the .env file I have configured my mail server etc but whatever I do the mail fails with

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269: Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [Connection refused #111]
```

I just want it to use my Settings!